# building an app in both android and iphone through iphone, how does it work?

Tags: cordova

I'm looking to develop a new app for both android and iphone.

It looks like the consensus is that phonegap is the best choice for this. From what it looks I will not need to code in java or obj. C, is this correct?

But can I develop all this on my windows computer? Must I have access to a mac to develop the iphone app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct, you can write in CSS/HTML/JavaScript, and you can build using [PhoneGap Build](https://build.phonegap.com/apps) (you will need an iOS key though). Remember however that there's lots of tradeoffs involved, you're not as 'close' to the OS as you would be with native coding for example. Whether that's a problem totally depends on your project.

Comment: i'm slightly confused by the getting started page here: http://phonegap.com/start  it looks like they are requiring eclipse and Xcode, why would I need to do that if I'm just coding in html/javascript?

Comment: The link I pasted was to PhoneGap Build, which doesn't require xcode. PhoneGap itself requires you to 'merge' the phonegap code and html/js/css into one project and build it, so you'll need xcode in that case. But PhoneGap Build does this for you.

Answer (score 1):

Using phonegap doesn't mean that you only need to write html/js/css.

For iOS, Android, and WP7, Phonegap is just a convenient way to develop "native + html" kind of apps, since it has prepared most of the native part, in most cases you don't have to write obj-C or Java or C# code by your own, but you still need them to run the app. Additionally, if you want more functionality by applying Phonegap plugins, the native code is what you have to deal with.

However, on the WebOS devices, your app can be pure html/js/css.

Answer (score 0):

Nope.

U need to write Javascript, HTML5 and CSS3. You will be asked to keep all these files in WWW folder. This folder can be copied to respective folders when building ios, android, windows etc. It is as simple as that.

For a DIY info - visit http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.3.0/guide_getting-started_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20Guides